# Изменение текста ссылки

Tags: javascript

подскажите как будет выглядеть код, который изменяет текст ссылки. Получение нового текста происходит с использованием синхронного запроса.

```
<a href="">Старый текст</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример, как это сделать на JavaScript:

```js
let newTextLink = 'Новый текст ссылки';
let link = document.querySelector('a');
link.innerText = newTextLink;
```

```html
<a href="#">Старый текст</a>
```

Ну и ссылочка, где можно узнать об этом подробнее https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Comment: Спасибо, а если мне надо изменить текст в параграфе. Получение нового текста происходит с использованием асинхронного запроса.
`<p>Старый текст</p>`                                                                                                                                                       То код будет выглядеть так? - `document.querySelector('p').innerText = 'new text';`

Comment: А то, что новый текст для ссылки происходит с использованием **синхронного** запроса, а получение нового текста в параграфе происходит с использованием **асинхронного** запроса. Это как-то влияет на код?                                                                                                                         
`let newTextLink = 'Новый текст параграфа';
let link = document.querySelector('p');
link.innerText = newTextP;`
`<p>Старый текст</p>`

Comment: Нет. Главное следить за тем, чтобы переменная, содержащая новый текст, была доступна в момент её использования

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.